# How can I cancel scrollTo if it's been triggered?

Tags: jquery-plugins, scrollto, jquery-events

I'd like to do something like:

```
var scrollable;
scrollable = $(window).scrollTo(99999, 99999);
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // cancel the scrollTo
    scrollable = null;
});
```

Comment: Inside the scroll() - obtain the window's current scroll position, and call scrollTo() on those coordinates.

Comment: hmmm, it seems like your advise would work, but the funny thing is that scrollTo triggers scroll. I need to attach scroll to a mouse event. I think

Comment: it queues the scroll is a very odd 0 delay way, which causes some issues depending on which version of jQuery you're on...not sure you *can* interrupt it, unless changing the `.scrollTo()` source is an option.

Comment: hmmm, interesting point @Nick. Looking at the source it's just the animate function. Is there a way to nullify or override animate after it's been executed? Might have to go sniffing deeper into jQuery source...

Comment: hmmm, so I went through the source and changed it to add `stop()` method, however this only briefly pauses the animate function. I think the animate is attached to the jQuery object, is that correct? If so, then I should be able to get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling I found this to work well.

```
$(window).scrollTo(99999, 99999);
$(window).click(function() {
    stopScroll();
});

 if(window.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', stopScroll, false);
 document.onmousewheel = stopScroll;

function stopScroll() {
    $(window).stop(true, false);  // Stops and dequeue's animations
}
```

No need to modify plugin or source!

Answer (score 1):

Based on jonobr1's code this works for me:

```
if(window.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', stopScroll, false);
document.onmousewheel = stopScroll;

function stopScroll() {
  $(window)._scrollable().stop(true, false);  // Stops and dequeue's animations
}
```

I added a call to stopScroll before my scrollTo calls in my event handlers too.